# Is it possible to connect a linear and a switched-mode power supply in parallel?

Tags: arduino, switch-mode-power-supply, parallel, led-strip, linear-regulator

I'm working on a project and I need to power some RGB LED strips; three strips that need 12 V, 5 A each. The thing is that I have one switched-mode power supply of 12 V, 10 A and some 12 V, 5 A power supplies that came with the LED strips/ I assume these are linear supplies.

So the SMPS was already installed; can't I add one of those 12 V, 5 A LED supplies in parallel with the SMPS to get the 15 A needed for three RGB LED strips?

The RGB LED strips will be controlled by an Arduino and all will have a common ground.

Comment: Can you specify if you mean "I power 2 strips from one supply and 1 from another" or "I want to join supplies' outputs and then feed all of that into LED strips"?

Comment: @Ilya I want to join supplies output to feed everything

Comment: Then Peter's correct. It's a bad idea.

Comment: @Ilya so the RGB connection from all the led strips will be connected to the arduino and the 12V from 1 strip will be connected to a separate power supply?

Comment: You really need to draw a schematic. I didn't understand this comment and I didn't understand your comment under Peter's answer either.

Comment: Feed the strips separately. Join grounds. Control signal may be the same, bring more information about strips.

Comment: But beware that Arduino consumes power too, even if not much, but it matters if you're maxing out the supplies. In theory, it's not a great idea to run power supply at max currents long term. Unnecessary stress. Even if it works now, things heat up, things age over time and lose efficiency, and these powers are already no joke. For 15A it's better to have 18A or 20A-capable supply.

Comment: ok so the 2 led strips will be connected together with the 12V 10A Power Supply and the control signal to the digital pins 3,4,5.
then the other one will be connected to the 12V 5A Power Supply and the control signal will be connected to the same digital pins 3,4,5.
all the grounds will be common.

Comment: what if instead of using the SMPS I use 4 power supplies (that came with the led strips, Sylvania P25258) in parallel to feed the 3 led strips (5m each) like it was 1 long strip (15m)?

Comment: @JoeX: As I said before,  you shouldn't connect power supplies in parallel unless they are designed to work in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't connect power supplies in parallel unless they are designed to work in parallel.

The two supplies will likely not be exactly the same voltage, so the higher voltage supply will supply all the current while the lower voltage supply delivers none.

In your application, you may be able to arrange for the 10 Amp supply to power two LED strips, while the 5 Amp supply powers the third strip.

The grounds of the two 12 volt supplies and the Arduino Ground should all be connected together.

Comment: so does that mean that the 3rd led strip, which have R, G, B and 12V connection will have the RGB connection shared but the 12V?

Comment: I mean all 3 led strips RGB connections will be connected to the Arduino and the 12V connection from 1 led strip will be connected to a separate Power Supply?

Comment: Still unclear. Draw the schematic. Words don't cut it.

Comment: ok, I'm downloading kicad, because circuito.io couldn't help me out for this...

Comment: @JoeX use the schematic editor that is included in this webpage ... go to your question and click `edit` ... then click the circuit icon .... after drawing the schematic, click `save and insert`